# Lock a Device to a Single PDF

Tags: android, pdf, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I need help to find and configure an app to convert my company Android tablet to kiosk mode.
We want to convert the tablet to see JUST ONE PDF.
The user could not have any interface or the possibility to change file or other.

I have tried with surelock, but the interface of acrobat still rest usable.

Could someone help me to understand how to resolve this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: follow this -http://wenchaojiang.github.io/blog/realise-Android-kiosk-mode/

Comment: @Adilhusen, thank you for the answer but I'm searching something like an app with this features.

Comment: yeah, but its a way you will implement any functionality after kiosk mode, after developing kiosk mode you simple load pdf in your app

Comment: Please don't use TAGs in your post title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you you have configured everything and Adobe Reader App is already present in allowed application, Tap **5 times** on device display and use password(“0000” is default) to access **SureLock Admin settings**.

• Tap on **Allowed Applications**.

•  Now tap on added **Adobe Reader app** > **Child Windows**.
   [image]

•  Uncheck box for **Select All** > Check/Enable **Adobe Reader**
  [image]

•  Check/Enable **viewer.ARViewerActivity** > Click **OK**
 [image]

Now, [**SureLock**](https://www.42gears.com/products/surelock/) will block all available option in Adobe Reader app except for viewing the PDF file.